# Surgery on $M\times S^1$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, surgery-theory

I've encountered such a question and I don't know if it's trivial or not.

Given a simply connected closed $n$-manifold $M$ ($n\geq 4$), $\pi_1(M\times S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and it can be killed by doing surgery on $S^1$. However, $\pi_1(SO(n))\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ and there are two choices of the surgery. Will these two ways lead to diffeomorphic manifolds?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick remark: if M is not 1-connected, then the two manifolds s(M) and s'(M) aren't necessarily even homotopy equivalent. An example would be an aspherical 3-manifold M, where the two spins are distinguished by their equivariant intersection forms. Equivalently, their top cells are attached differently. See Plotnick, Equivariant Intersection Forms, Knots in S4, and Rotations in 2-spheres, TAMS 6 (1986), 543-575.  It seems likely that s(M) = s'(M) if M is highly connected.

Comment: Oh, it seems that it's not a trivial problem in general. The article may be useful. Thanks for the comment! @DannyRuberman